# Не могу задать в дизайнере DependencyProperty для UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Есть юзерконтрол. Есть у него свойство?

```
public int PagesCount
{
    get { return (int)GetValue(PagesCountProperty); }
    set { SetValue(PagesCountProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty PagesCountProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("PagesCount", typeof(int), typeof(UC_Pager), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(1));
```

Есть в его xaml разметке такой элемент

```
<ComboBox Width="50"
          IsEditable="True"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Pages}" 
          SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentPage}"/>
```

Вот что такое Pages

```
public int[] Pages
{
    get
    {
        var c = PagesCount;
        var res = new int[c];
        for (var i = 0; i < c; i++)
            res[i] = i + 1;
        return res;
    }
}
```

Короче возвращает массив от 1 до PagesCount.

А вот я уже использую свой контрол

```
<tools:UC_Pager DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" CurrentPage="{Binding CurrentPage}" PagesCount="3">
```

Я уж не говорю про биндинг PagesCount, оно даже в таком явном виде не срабатывает. Ставлю точку останова в свойство Pages и вижу, что PagesCount = 1, хотя я в контструкторе явно указал что оно равно 3.

Самое интересное, что у меня есть еще команды, типа переместиться на следующую, предыдущую и тд... и кнопки с командами на следующую и на последнюю становятся активны. А значит в них PagesCount таки тот, который я установил. Странно все это.

Comment: Pages - это тоже свойство зависимости?

Comment: @Vlad, нет. Просто свойство

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вероятно, проблема в том, что вы не уведомляете внешний код об изменении свойства `Pages`. Т.е. вам нужно сделать примерно следующее в code-behind:

```
public partial class PagesControl : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    protected override void OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Если изменилось свойство PagesCount - сообщить об изменении Pages
        if (e.Property == PagesCountProperty)
        {
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Pages));
        }

        base.OnPropertyChanged(e);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty PagesCountProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("PagesCount", typeof(int), typeof(PagesControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(1));

    public int PagesCount
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(PagesCountProperty); }
        set { SetValue(PagesCountProperty, value); }
    }

    public int[] Pages
    {
        get
        {
            var c = PagesCount;
            var res = new int[c];
            for (var i = 0; i < c; i++)
                res[i] = i + 1;
            return res;
        }
    }

    // Реализация INotifyPropertyChanged
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = null)
    {
        var tmp = PropertyChanged;
        if (tmp != null)
            tmp(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

А в разметке контрола просто привязаться к этим свойствам:

```
<ComboBox
      ItemsSource="{Binding Pages, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:PagesControl}}}"
      SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentPage, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:PagesControl}}}"/>
```

Comment: Да, я как задал вопрос, так сразу разобрался. только забыл написать об этом. Все так, как вы и сказали. Очень помогает порой найти ответ правильно сформулированный вопрос. Причем именно на этапе его формулирования )